# Function does not take 0 arguments, but I'm only trying to open a function up, not pass anything

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arguments

I'm working with a partner, and we are both confused. VS tells us that "Function does not take 0 arguments" But we are both confused as to what that means. We are simply calling the arguments in an "if statement"

Would appreciate help on what I am misunderstanding. I am very new to functions and just trying to grasp what I am doing incorrectly.

```
    int gradeSelection();
int choiceGrade;
char menu;

switch (choiceGrade)
{
case 1:
    cout << "You have selected First Grade";
    menuDisplay();
    if (menu == '+')
    {                                // addition first grade
        doAdditionFirstGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '-') {                          // subtraction first grade
        doSubtractionFirstGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '*') {                          // multiplication first grade
        doMultiplicationFirstGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '/') {                          // division first grade
        doDivisionFirstGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '@') {                          // mixture first grade
        doMixtureFirstGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '0') {                          //exit program
        cout << "Thank you for using the Math Tutor!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid input, please try again" << endl;
    }

    break;

case 2: cout << "You have selected Second Grade";
    menuDisplay();
    if (menu == '+')
    {                                // addition second grade
        doAdditionSecondGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '-') {                          // subtraction second grade
        doSubtractionSecondGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '*') {                          // multiplication second grade
        doMultiplicationSecondGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '/') {                          // division second grade
        doDivisionSecondGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '@') {                          // mixture second grade
        doMixtureSecondGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '0') {                          //exit program
        cout << "Thank you for using the Math Tutor!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid input, please try again" << endl;
    }

    break;

case 3: cout << "You hace selected Third Grade";
    menuDisplay();
    if (menu == '+')
    {                                // addition third grade
        doAdditionThirdGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '-') {                          // subtraction third grade
        doSubtractionThirdGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '*') {                          // multiplication third grade
        doMultiplicationThirdGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '/') {                          // division third grade
        doDivisionThirdGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '@') {                          // mixture third grade
        doMixtureThirdGrade();
    }
    else if (menu == '0') {                          //exit program
        cout << "Thank you for using the Math Tutor!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid input, please try again" << endl;
    }

    break;

case 0: cout << "Goodbye!";

default: cout << "Sorry, that was an invalid input.";

}
    return 0;
```

}

in the "doAdditionFirstGrade" and the ones similar, is where I am getting the error.

They are called at the very beginning as:

```
void welcomeMessage();
int gradeSelection();
void menuDisplay();
int doAdditionFirstGrade(int num);
```

etc. (not going to link every bit of code to avoid confusion).

Then the actual function itself is:

```
    int doAdditionFirstGrade(int num) {
}
    return correct;
```

I didn't add all the code in the middle, because that part is not relevant to what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Off topic: `int doAdditionFirstGrade(int num) { } return correct;` Strongly recommend placing the `return` statement inside the function body. `int doAdditionFirstGrade(int num) { return correct; }` This may be helpful reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions

Comment: The declaration `int doAdditionFirstGrade(int num)` indicates that your function takes 1 argument, of type `int`. Then you can't call it without supplying a corresponding actual argument.

Comment: "int doAdditionFirstGrade(int num) { } return correct; Strongly recommend placing the return statement inside the function body. "

yeah sorry that code snippet was just to cut down from pasting all 1200 lines of code, the return statement is in the body of it, i just left the return statement there so you could see what it was returning.

Comment: You have a problem, Colin. No one can give a meaningful answer without meaningful code. If you have thousands of lines of code, you have broken one of the most important rules of programming: Don't write so much code without testing. Write a bit of code. Test it. Write a bit more. Test it.  That way if something goes wrong, most of the time you know where. It's in the stuff you just added.

Comment: I cant help my team mate wrote all this code without me and I have to jump in. I understand the biggest rule if testing it as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology is to call a function, not to open it. When you do this you must pass the correct arguments to the function.

The error message is telling you that you are attempting to call a function passing no arguments, while the function requires arguments. General ways to resolve this are:

- remove the function calls,
- provide the correct arguments for the calls, or
- change the functions so that they do not require arguments.

I'd say that the 2nd one is the most common resolution, while the first one I listed is actually the least likely to be the correct approach. Which one is correct depends on the situation.

I can't really tell from the code you posted how the pieces of your program should fit together. You are not using the return value of doAdditionFirstGrade() and don't appear to have a value for, or be using its parameter, so my guess is that you want something more like:

```
// stuff ...

void welcomeMessage();
int gradeSelection();

char menuDisplay();             
void doAdditionFirstGrade();
// other declarations

int someFunction()
{
    int gradeSelection();
    int choiceGrade;
    char menu;

    // get choice grade somehow

    switch (choiceGrade)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You have selected First Grade";

        menu = menuDisplay();
        if (menu == '+')
        {                                // addition first grade
            doAdditionFirstGrade();
        }
        else if (menu == '-') {                          // subtraction first grade
            doSubtractionFirstGrade();
        }
        else if (menu == '*') {                          // multiplication first grade
            doMultiplicationFirstGrade();
        }
        else if (menu == '/') {                          // division first grade
            doDivisionFirstGrade();
        }
        else if (menu == '@') {                          // mixture first grade
            doMixtureFirstGrade();
        }
        else if (menu == '0') {                          //exit program
            cout << "Thank you for using the Math Tutor!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You have entered an invalid input, please try again" << endl;
        }

        break;

    // other cases

    default: 
        cout << "Sorry, that was an invalid input.";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void doAdditionFirstGrade() 
{
    // do stuff
    return;
}
```

If doAdditionFirstGrade() really does require a parameter, then this is wrong and you must get the proper value somehow and pass it in the function call.

Note that I have also changed the usage of the menuDisplay() function to return the value of the choice rather than (apparently) use a global variable to communicate the result. I'd consider this an improvement, but it is not what you are asking about and it would require you to make a corresponding change to the menuDisplay() function itself.

Comment: Like I said, i'm new to functions, so HELP is appreciated over criticism.

Comment: If you read my statement, I replied saying the return statement is in the body of the code, i just didnt add every single line, and included the return statement so you could see the return.

Comment: Your problem is that you are calling functions that require arguments without providing those arguments. I outlined the three potential ways that this problem can be resolved. This was meant as help. I seriously doubt the first way is a solution in your case. I can't know whether the 2nd or 3rd should be used without knowing how the pieces of your code fit together, though I would guess that you want the third alternative.

Comment: It is important that you understand that you are trying to call functions and when you do, you MUST pass the arguments that are required by the function. That is what the error message means. I can try to add a code sample for my guess of what you want to do, but have a couple of other things I have to do first.

Comment: @ColinPowers, Better?